# CoNP and NPhard intersection

Tags: complexity-theory

Can a problem be both *NP-Hard* and *CoNP*?

Can a problem be both *NP* and *CoNP-Hard*?

Comment: [no, unless P = NP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-NP)

Comment: I do not think so. NP=CoNP is a first level complexity hierarchy issue. What you are stating is second level. Inferring something at the second level from the first level does not seem logical.

Comment: Wouldn't NP = coNP do it? If NP = coNP, than any NP-complete problems is both NP-hard and in coNP. And as far as I know, NP = coNP does not imply P = NP.

Comment: @PeterShor that is what I was explaining here. I am just seeing the possibility what if the problem is in CoNP and NP-hard but not in NP? Do we have a choice here like that? That is the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a problem which is both NP-hard and in coNP if and only if NP = coNP.

If NP = coNP, than NP-complete problems (like 3-SAT) are both NP-hard and in coNP.

On the other hand, if any NP-hard problem is in coNP, then all problems in NP are reducible to it, so all problems in NP are in coNP so NP ⊆ coNP. Now, since the complement of NP is coNP, and vice versa, we also have  coNP ⊆ NP. This means NP = coNP.

The question of whether NP = coNP is open, but most theoretical computer scientists do not think it is very likely.

Comment: ah ic the problem does not have to be in NP (got it) and thankyou.